# PUT Object to AWS S3 via HTTP through VPC Endpoint with proper ACL?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, https

I am using an HTTPS client to PUT an object to Amazon S3 from an EC2 instance within a VPC that has an S3 VPC Endpoint configured. The target Bucket has a Bucket Policy that only allows access from specific VPCs, so authentication via IAM is impossible; I have to use HTTPS GET and PUT to read and write Objects.

This works fine as described, but I'm having trouble with the ACL that gets applied to the Object when I PUT it to the Bucket. I've played with setting a Canned ACL using HTTP headers like the following, but neither results in the correct behavior:

```
x-amz-acl: private
```

If I set this header, the Object is private but it can only be read by the root email account so this is no good. Others need to be able to access this Object via HTTPS.

```
x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control
```

I totally thought this Canned ACL would do the trick, however, it resulted in unexpected behavior, namely that the Object became *World Readable*! I'm also not sure how the Owner of the Object was decided either since it was created via HTTPS, in the console the owner is listed as a seemingly random value. This is the documentation description:

> Both the object owner and the bucket owner get FULL_CONTROL over the
>   object. If you specify this canned ACL when creating a bucket, Amazon
>   S3 ignores it.

This is totally baffling me, because according to the Bucket Policy, only network resources of approved VPCs should even be able to list the Object, let alone read it! Perhaps it has to do with the union of the ACL and the Bucket Policy and I just don't see something.

Either way, maybe I'm going about this all wrong anyway. How can I PUT an object to S3 via HTTPS and set the permissions on that object to match the Bucket Policy, or otherwise make the Bucket Policy authoritative over the ACL?

Here is the Bucket Policy for good measure:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-12345678"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that S3 ACLs and Bucket Policies work is the concept of "Least Privilege".

Your bucket policy only specifies ALLOW for the specified VPC. No one else is granted ALLOW access. This is NOT the same as denying access.

This means that your Bucket or object ACL is granting access.

In the S3 console double check who the file owner is after the PUT.

Double check the ACL for the bucket. What rights have your granted at the bucket level?

Double check the rights that you are using for the PUT operation. Unless you have granted public write access or the PUT is being ALLOWED by the bucket policy, the PUT must be using a signature. This signature will determine the permissions for the PUT operation and who owns the file after the PUT. This is determined by the ACCESS KEY used for the signature.

Your x-amz-acl should contain bucket-owner-full-control.

[EDIT after numerous comments below]

The problem that I see is that you are approaching security wrong in your example. I would not use the bucket policy. Instead I would create an IAM role and assign that role to the EC2 instances that are writing to the bucket. This  means that the PUTs are then signed with the IAM Role Access Keys. This preserves the ownership of the objects. You can then have the ACL being bucket-owner-full-control and public-read (or any supported ACL permissions that you want).

Comment: There is no signature because there is no access key, the policy is using a condition to allow the PUT based on the origin VPC of the HTTP request. So it is "public write" but with a condition, so the ACL "owner" in this context is meaningless. The owner ends up as just a seemingly random hex value, maybe an md5 of the request? I've checked all of the things you mentioned, but none of them indicate that the object should be public read/write, yet it is! None of the other objects act this way. I will try next is adding an explicit deny to the Bucket Policy for the opposite condition.

Comment: This means that the owner is anonymous which when you set bucket-owner-full-control gives everyone access. There is your security hole and a BIG one.

Comment: @Marty *"There is no signature because there is no access key, the policy is using a condition to allow the PUT based on the origin VPC of the HTTP request."*  That's not a valid configuration, as it allows access without requiring authentication.  The account whose user uploads an object becomes the account that owns the object (not the bucket owner)... so if you use `s3:PutObject` without authenticating as an actual user, *the anonymous user* owns the object.  `bucket-owner-full-control` preserves permissions for the object owner, too, which is in this case the anonymous user.

Comment: Sorry, @JohnHanley, I didn't see your previous comment when I initially started writing mine.

Comment: Aha, well that makes sense. It just doesn't make sense then why it doesn't just say "anonymous" in the console instead of just some random string. It would have been obvious what was happening if that was the case! So what is the best way forward then? How do I allow an "anonymous user" to put and get objects based on the condition I've set forth. Is there some special "Owner" I can explicitly set for the Objects when I create them? I see that's possible to do with the headers. It must be possible since I have objects in the bucket that are behaving as I would expect them to.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot. No problem :). You always have good advice. I have also edited my answer to provide a recommendation to improve upon his problem.

Comment: @Marty. I have improved my answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley I would love to use an IAM Role, however, these particular instances are part of a managed service and I have no ability to assign a Role. This is what caused this entire convoluted setup in the first place :) That being said, I might instead try to add an additional Allow for a federation token and limit the VPC authentication to GET only. I am going to explore custom ACLs a bit more first though because that would be the simplest way forward if I can figure it out.

Comment: I would then recommend looking into Cognito to provide authentication, authorization and temporary credentials. The authentication to Cognito can be done in just about any programming language and there are lots of examples on the Internet. One issue is that now you are storing the username and password on the EC2 instance.

Comment: @JohnHanley I will use STS if I have to use credentials, I am already creating federated sessions via STS for the EC2 instances (they actually retrieve those credentials from this exact Bucket). I was trying to avoid using those credentials for putting objects to the bucket, because it makes the bucket policy more complicated. I'll be weighing all the pros and cons as I'm developing things here, but thanks for helping me identify the problem!